# Invoke command pipeline in R and capture the output

Tags: r

Suppose I have two files `fileA` and `fileB` with command outputs as:

```
$vcf-query fileA | grep chr2:233485652
chr2:233485652  T   NORMAL=T/T  TUMOR=T/A
```

and the `grep chr2:233485652` return nothing or NULL for `fileB`:

```
$vcf-query fileB | grep chr2:233485652
```

My question is how I can invoke these pipelines in R using `system2()` and return `TRUE` if there is output like from `fileA` and return 'FALSE' otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're interested in testing for *any output*, you can do this:

```
length(system2(cmd,args,stdout=T))>0L;
```

where `cmd` is your command and `args` are the arguments.

This works because `system2()`, when given `stdout=T`, returns the output as a character vector, one line per element.

For example (running on Cygwin):

```
length(system2('echo','-n',stdout=T))>0L; ## print nothing
## [1] FALSE
length(system2('echo','blah',stdout=T))>0L; ## print blah
## [1] TRUE
length(system2('echo',stdout=T))>0L; ## print an empty line
## [1] TRUE
length(system2('grep','blah',stdout=T))>0L; ## grep for blah; I pressed <C-d> right away
## [1] FALSE
## Warning message:
## running command ''grep' blah' had status 1
length(system2('grep','blah',stdout=T))>0L; ## grep for blah; I typed blah, then <C-d>
## blah
## [1] TRUE
```

---

Note that the pipeline syntax can be passed in `args`. For example:

```
system2('echo','asdf| cat -vet',stdout=T);
## [1] "asdf$"
length(system2('echo','asdf| cat -vet',stdout=T))>0L;
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @bgoldst~ it is very helpful!